# Need help applying regression model to dataset in R (sports data)

Tags: r, regression, predict

Update: Solved!

I'm currently trying to create a regression model for football that predicts a team's total points based on their pass yards and rush yards. I was able to get all the way to figuring out the regression equation but from here I do not know how to "plug in" the formula.

The data table is essentially all 32 NFL teams listed in rows and their offensive stats listed in columns

Code:

```
# 1. Import
Offense <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
#2 View
show (Offense)
#3 Attach so headers can be referenced
attach (Offense)
#4 Create Regression Model
mod1 <-lm(Total.Points ~ Pass.Yds + Rush.Yds)
summary(mod1)
#Formula obtained from summary: -255.60178 + .10565(Pass) + .12154(Rush)
#Plug in the Regression Equation
predict(mod1)
```

Output: https://imgur.com/a/AbTNF

I see that at the end it applied the regression equation to all 32 rows, but how do I

1. get it to display in a ranked list
2. get it to display, say, the team name as well as the projected score (so I don't have to wonder what team "1" or "2" refer to

Since I have the equation, could I also just write a loop function that ran the equation for every row of data I have and print the results?

I'm a beginner so much appreciated!

Update: Came up with this

```
####Part 2. Interpretation

#1. Examining quality of model
summary(mod1)
cor(Pass.Yds, Rush.Yds)

#2. Formula obtained from summary: -255.60178 + .10565(Pass) + .12154(Rush)

#3. Predicted Points (Descending Order)
proj <- sort(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE)

proj

#4. Corresponding Name (Descending)
name <- Team[order(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE)]

name

#Data Frame
Projections <- data.frame(name, proj)

Projections
```

While bbrot provided a much simpler version

Comment: Could you fix the formatting? That will help us help you...

Comment: Fixed! wasn't sure how to embed the image.

Comment: You probably want something like `Offense$predicted_points <- predict(mod1)` . Then you have your predictions in the original data frame which you can order as you like.

Comment: Other minor points. Don't use `attach`. Instead do `lm(Total.Points ~ Pass.Yds + Rush.Yds, data = Offense)`. It keeps your workspace cleaner.

Comment: @dash2 can you explain Offense$predicted_points <- predict(mod1)? What is the "$predicted_points" coming from?

Comment: @dash2 Edit: I understand. From what you gave me though, I only have a list of predicted scores. How can I write something out that can spit a list out for me of, say, the team name? Ex: the 1st team in the list (Atlanta Falcons) has the second highest points. I only knew that because I looked up what the first team was: how can I automate this?

Comment: Just look at your data frame `Offense`. You'll find it has a new column. I assume the team names are in there. You can do `View(Offense)` to get a nice scrollable view. To explicitly order it by predicted score: `Offense[order(Offense$predicted_points, decreasing = TRUE),]` or with dplyr, `Offense %>% arrange(desc(predicted_points))`

Comment: @dash2 oh dang so that's what Table$newcolumnname <-predict(regression equation) does! Just figured out how to expand off of this too, much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Teams` is the vector of team names, something like `cbind(Teams[order(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE)], sort(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE))` should do...

**Edit:** Your `Teams` vector seems to be a factor. In this case, the following commands are going to work:

```
# returns a character matrix
cbind(as.character(Teams)[order(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE)],
      sort(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE))

# returns a data frame
data.frame(Teams = Teams[order(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE)],
           Points = sort(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE))
```

Comment: when I try that, here's what it gives me (doesn't give the actual team name but numbers instead.)

  [,1]     [,2]
2    21 492.2012
1     2 477.9364
12   32 453.2245
3    20 427.0736
5     9 419.2375
7    24 405.9986
10   26 402.2616
4    12 394.7735
6     1 391.8853
8    14 386.2176
11    4 384.8168
14   31 384.3261
24    7 375.8863
28    6 374.6063
18   29 373.4797
9    27 371.4527
19   30 355.5995
21    3 355.3864
15    5 354.2035
13   16 351.9924
16   25 343.5169
20   11 337.9522
25   15 336.5038

Comment: Well, that's hard to read. Anyways, you need to replace `Teams` with the object name of the vector of team names. I there a column of team names in the CSV file? If yes, what's its name?

Comment: sorry about that, not sure how to format on here yet. the vector name was "Team", which I adapted your formula to. Instead of "Atlanta Falcons", however, it displays "21".

Comment: Update: if I just run "Team[order(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE)]", it displays the team names in order which is great. It only acts up when I try to add in that second bit of coding (sort(predict(mod1), decreasing = TRUE))

Comment: Perfect. I figured it out myself but I did a MUCH more sloppy way. Updated the OP just to show you haha. Much thanks for your help!